# ASP.NET MVC - MasterPage cannot be applied to this page because the control collection is read-only. If the page contains code blocks

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This error message doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of MVC:

```
MasterPage cannot be applied to this page because the control collection is read-only. If the page contains code blocks, make sure they are placed inside content controls (i.e. <asp:Content runat=server />)
```

What's it mean?

My view looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Site.Controllers.ProductCategoryController.ProductListViewModel>" MasterPageFile="~/site.master" %>

<% foreach (var prod in Model.Products) { %>
    <li><%=prod.Description%></li>                                          
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it is quite a simple mistake. The problem was my view code wasn't wrapped in a `content` control (which maps to a `contentplaceholder` in the master page).

Of course my view should be like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Site.Controllers.ProductCategoryController.ProductListViewModel>" MasterPageFile="~/site.master" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent">
    <% foreach (var prod in Model.Products) { %>
        <li><%=prod.Description%></li>                                          
    <% } %>         
</asp:Content>
```

Pretty obvious but I just couldn't see it!

And the error message didn't really help me.

Comment: Appears as though this is ASP.net WebForms, not Razor, which is common for most MVC Apps.

Comment: To be clear it is ASP.NET MVC WebForms view engine. Not to be confused with ASP.NET WebForms!